# WordPress menu dropdown showing BEHIND video object

Tags: css, wordpress, object, video, z-index

I'm working on this website: http://www.oklahomainsightstv.com/ and I'm trying to get the navigation drop down to show up ON TOP of the video object. I've tried a few versions of z-index in the CSS but nothing has worked.

This is my code:

```
<div id="hero" style="z-index:-1; position:relative;">

<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" width="437" height="266" id="viddler_e3f5a526"><param name="movie" value="http://www.viddler.com/simple/e3f5a526/" /><param name="wmode" value="transparent" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><embed src="http://www.viddler.com/simple/e3f5a526/" width="437" height="266" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="true" name="viddler_e3f5a526"></embed></object>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a browser bug !
Flash, iframes are visible above the menu. Place video object far from the menu.

Comment: It's a template my client had to have. the template designer end up figuring out a fix for it. - Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Without testing it myself, a quick search revealed that there are two things you might not be doing:

1. Add the `wmode` parameter to your video object and use the value "transparent": `<param name="wmode" value="transparent" />`
2. Make sure you specify the `position:relative;` style to the menu with the z-order. Otherwise, the z-order won't be applied.

If that doesn't work, you may have encountered a limitation of a given browser, in which case, you may have to design the site so that plugins don't have the opportunity to overlap.

[Sources](http://drupal.org/node/516958)

Comment: I did both of those things and it's still now working. I've added my code above.

Comment: Did you try putting your menu's z-index to a high number? I don't know how well negative z-indexes work.

Comment: That's it as far as my ideas go. This is a fairly common problem, so it might simply be the browser you're using doesn't work correctly. Sorry I couldn't be more help.

Comment: It is just Firefox (I just discovered) which is so backwards. Usually I'm having problems with IE - LOL. Thanks anyway!